# Using json in d3

Tags: json, d3.js

I wanted to us the Day / Hour Heatmap example

http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084

I can use something like this to use JSON:

```
        d3.jso("data.json",
        function(d) {
          return {
            day: +d.day,
            hour: +d.hour,
            value: +d.value
          };
        },
```

How is the JSON format should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, this is what the format should look like:

```
{
    "946702811" : 12,
    "946702812" : 53
    ....
}
```

- Link to documentation: http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/v2/
- Example JSON: http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/v2/datas-hours.json